# Migrating J2EE style Project to OSGi Style using the OSGi declarative services

Tags: spring, osgi

I am new to OSGi and am using Equinox "Virgo Tomcat Server" (VTS) along with eclipse blueprint, and got big assignment to do in limited time 
There is application already developed in J2EE Style 
By using JSP->Struts2->Spring->MySQL and SOAP Web Services. 
-There are various layer in the existing architecture

Simple Request flow is as mention below

From UI layer->it goes to strus2 configration-> it goes to Spring Configuration->From Spring configuration xml (that is module wise application context xml) Struts Action class is called -From Struts Action class layer -> it goes to Task layer->handler layer->Service Layer -> Adapter or DAO layer ->DB in some cases from service layer call also goes to WebService layer and communicate with Back-end legacy system

My Queries are as Follows 
Q1] From UI/JSP to up-to strtus2 action layer code for every module should be club together in to a single .war file say "onlinebank.war" and from struts2 action onwords module wise code in every layer should go in to Module wise OSGi bundles 
For e.g. if there are 10 modules there should be 10 osgi bundles 
And each module wise bundle should contain module specific code from every layer after action layer and there should be communication between one war "onlinebank.war" and 10 osgi bundles

Q2]To take Q1 to next level 
If there are 10 modules then instead of crunching module specific code in one OSGi bundle,
I have to create 3 bundles for each module(XXXAPI,XXXMain,XXXConfig) 
for e.g. TestModule
I]  TestModuleAPI (will contain only interfaces and abstract classes) 
II] TestModuleMain (will contain implementation of interfaces and abstract classes and will provide some default functionality) 
III]TestModuleConfig (will be accessing the default functionality of Main Bundle Via API Bundle and also provide some customize/new functionality)

So if there are 10 Module and 3 OSGi Bundles for each module (API,Main,Config) then for 10 bundles there should be 3*10=30 bundles and there should be proper communication between -single war "onlinebank.war" and the 30 bundles 
Also there should be proper communication among 30 bundles it self to resolve the dependencies and works together properly/synchronously

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Regards, 
Gokul

Answer (score 0):

This is a big task you are tackling. I did such a migration and am quite familiar with OSGi. Still it took about 2 months. So you should first not underestimate the problems you will be facing. 
The next thing is that a typical spring application is not well modularized. As there are no private/public packages in JSE developers tend to ignore module boundaries. The modules often also do not have a clean and small API at all so people known what they should access and what not.

So I think your first task is to refactor the application so each bundle offers a minimal API and other modules only access the API. For this task it might make sense to use an architecture tool that allows to define and control these accesses. While still in spring you create beans from a service interface from the API. Later in OSGi the API will allow to define clean OSGi services. If you skip this step then OSGi will not have big advantages. OSGi only works well if the application is strictly modularized.

Then for the actual OSGi migration I can only urge you to hire some specialist to help you. It will be a waste of time and resources if you do this alone.